# Link one service to another service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

I have individual kubernetes containers up and running. Can someone please help me how to link them?
I have worked on docker compose and there it works like this:

```
redis:
    image: redis
    hostname: redis
    expose:
      - "6379"

  nginx:
    image: xxx.xx.xx.xx:5000/nginx:0.1
    expose:
      - "8080"
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - active-webserver
      - passive-webserver

  active-webserver:
    image: xxx.xx.xx.xx:5000/webserver:0.1
    hostname: active-webserver
    depends_on:
      - redis
    links:
      - redis
    expose:
      - "8081"
    ports:
      - "8090:8081"

  passive-webserver:
    image: xxx.xx.xx.xx:5000/webserver:0.1
    hostname: passive-webserver
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - kafka
    links:
      - redis
      - kafka
    expose:
      - "8081"
    ports:
      - "8091:8081"
```

But when coming to kubernetes, I have no clue how to proceed. I have service and deployment files created after using kompose but it actually broke the links between the code.

Service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml
    kompose.version: 1.5.0 (999278f)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8080"
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

And my deployment file is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yaml
    kompose.version: 1.5.0 (999278f)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: xxx.xx.xx.xx:5000/nginx:0.1
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

In kubernetes the atomic unit of container scheduling is a Pod, a pod can contain multiple containers but the pod is your unit of scaling. So if the containers are linked and you always want them to scale them together then put them all in the same pod.

If you don't, if you might want more of one container than another or want to scale them independently then the best you can do is one or a few of the following to achieve some kind of order.

Create a namespace to put your whole "stack" in. Have a deployment(or whatever) for each group of containers you might want to scale independently, but keep them together in one namespace. That way your internal dns names (if you are using kubedns) will be, say, redis.mystack.svc.cluster.local (where mystack is the name of your namespace and redis is the name of your service in front of, in this case, your redis pods).

Use labels to tie the different portions of your app together. Labels are a great way of organizing you stack. For instance give each resource a label of "app: mystack". Then you can do things like `kubectl get pods -l app=mystack`

Use a tool like helm ( https://github.com/kubernetes/helm ) it has a concept of grouping resources together into one "application".

Any of these can be used together without issue.

Comment: Ok this will put the pods in one namespace, but my real question is how will the applications resolve dependencies?? Like in the above attached docker-compse file, we give links and depends in yaml, what is the equivalent in kubernetes manifest?

Comment: In raw kubernetes there is nothing. Networking wise if containers are in the same pod they can addressed via localhost (127.0.0.1) if they are not and you are running kubedns kubernetes services will get the internal dns name of <servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local